# get method value from java spring boot repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, repository

my query returns an INT, which would be the number of rows affected.

I would like to know, how do I retrieve this value in the controller or service, or in the repository itself

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE tb_pessoal_funcionarios SET salario = CAST(salario+(salario * :percentualAumento)/100 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) "
                  + "WHERE id IN (:funcionarioId) "
                      + "AND (:alterarFuncionariosDemitidos IS true OR condicao <> 'Inativo')")
void AlterarSalarioSelecionadosPorPercentual(Double percentualAumento, Long funcionarioId, Boolean alterarFuncionariosDemitidos);
```

i need get method value from java spring boot repository

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an int as return value.

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE tb_pessoal_funcionarios SET salario = CAST(salario+(salario * :percentualAumento)/100 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) "
                  + "WHERE id IN (:funcionarioId) "
                      + "AND (:alterarFuncionariosDemitidos IS true OR condicao <> 'Inativo')")
int AlterarSalarioSelecionadosPorPercentual(Double percentualAumento, Long funcionarioId, Boolean alterarFuncionariosDemitidos);
```

Comment: ok, but in this case, how can I retrieve this value, for a possible validation?

Comment: You call AlterarSalarioSelecionadosPorPercentual and then you get the value

Comment: my question is if I would do this in the Service or in the Controller

I'm just starting out in the area. could you please give me an example?

Comment: I would do this in the service.